# Regex removes certain words from my string - Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, replace

The below code is to lookup a dictionary and replace string with values corresponding to dict's key.

```
d = {"lh": "left hand"}
sentence = "lh l.h. lh. -lh- l.h .lh plh phli lhp 1lh lh1"
pattern_replace = r'(?<!(\w|\d))(\.)?({})(\.)?(?!(\w|\d))'.format('|'.join(sorted(re.escape(k) for k in d)))
sentence = re.sub(pattern_replace, lambda m: d.get(m.group(0)), sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
sentence
```

Can someone help me understand why my code omits certain words?

It removes `lh` preceeded and followed with a `.` i.e., `lh.` and `.lh`. How to overcome this?

I get the output `left hand l.h.  -left hand- l.h  plh phli lhp 1lh lh1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the lookup dict you need to get capture group 3 instead of the whole match with `m.group(0)`

**Note** that `\w` also matches `\d`.

Now your pattern looks like:

```
(?<!(\w|\d))(\.)?(lh)(\.)?(?!(\w|\d))
```

But you can rewrite the structure of the pattern to just use group 1 `m.group(1)` for the dict key:

```
(?<!\w)\.?(lh)\.?(?!\w)
           ^^ 
           dict key
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BZCun/1)

Comment: Makes sense now!!